# Add text to a <p> tag by using the ID of the body tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert some text in a [paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)
tag, but here the paragraph tag doesn't have an ID. So, using the ID of the body tag I want to insert text. How can I do that?

Following is my HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body dir="ltr" id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true">
        <p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to add text using JavaScript in the *p* tag.

I want that text to come from another variable. Is it possible using [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)?

Comment: The respective jQuery solution for this would be `$("p:first-of-type").html("something");`. Reference: [:first-of-type-selector | jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**JavaScript solution:**
To add text in the first `p` tag.

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML="Whatever text!";
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML="Whatever text!";
//alert(list);
```

```html
<html>

<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body dir="ltr" id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true">
  <p>
    <br data-mce-bogus="1">
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is that `[0]`, means what it does?

Comment: Because without it, that didn't work! Every time we have to write that `[0]`?

Comment: Yup. [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which may contain multiple instances of [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node). If your HTML had multiple `p` tags, the `HTMLCollection` would contain one `Node` per.

Answer (score 4):

Use the *find* method to find *children*...

```js
(function(){
    $("#tinymce").find("p").html("asd");
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body dir="ltr" id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true">
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [immediate child selector `>`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), along with the `body` selector to target the `<p>` element:

```
$("body > p").text("new text");
```

Additionally, if you have only one `<p>` element in your whole HTML document then you can use the tagname selector directly:

```
 $("p").text("new text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Ani Menon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600453/add-text-to-a-p-tag-by-using-the-id-of-the-body-tag-in-javascript/37720014#37720014), the jQuery version of the same solution would be achieved by using [`:first-of-type` selector in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p:first-of-type").html("something");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p")[0].innerHTML = 'success';
document.querySelectorAll("p)[1].innerHTML = 'another success';
```

The index 0 and 1 represented into []. Are for targeting each paragraph tag my recommendation use this method only for one p tag...

```html
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Example JS add text to p</title>
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$("p").html("Write Your Text");
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
 $("body > p").text("YourText");
```

```js
$("body > p").text("YourText");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body dir="ltr" id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true">
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OMG. who upvoted this. this is totally wrong solution. p is not parent of body tag.

Comment: what does closest do?? `For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.`